# count parameter is ignored when querying user_timeline in tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I'm trying to use the `tweepy` library in one of my python projects. When I try the following code that creates a tweepy cursor to fetch a user's timeline status messages, the count parameter is always ignored.

```
def search(self, username, keyword, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret):
    #start twitter auth
    try:
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        user = api.get_user(username)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        self.error = str(e)
        return
    self.followercount = user.followers_count
    self.screenname = user.screen_name
    results = []
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username, count=2).items():
        try:
            tweet = status._json
```

In this instance, the count is set to 2 in the Cursor object, yet it receives all of them. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tweepy.Cursor()`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/cursor.py#L14) does not appear to recognize a `count` argument. In fact, `count` is not mentioned anywhere in [`tweepy/cursor.py`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/cursor.py), the module where `tweepy.Cursor` is defined. Instead, it looks like you might want to use:

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username).items(2):
```

passing the limit to `items()` instead of as the `count` keyword argument. See [this section](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html#limits) in the tweepy [Cursor tutorial](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html#cursor-tutorial).

Comment: When I use `.items(2)`, it returns zero results, whereas there are results when I use `.items()` without any arguments. That's really strange because the documentation suggests that items(n) should work.

Comment: That is very strange. When you use just `.items()` does it return all items? Does using `.pages(n)` work as expected?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, I received a notification about this question today. After doing some trial-error, `items(n)` did work at that time.